# How do python Pil getdata() to hex fast?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

```
  fil="IMG1.JPG"
  im = Image.open(fil) 
  pixels=list(im.getdata())
  hex_list=[]
  for px in pixels:
    he='%02x%02x%02x' % px
    hex_list.append(he)
```

The code works but when the images are large is too slow, it is not possible faster? it is possible to getdata() directly in hex?

Thank you for interest? Good works.

Comment: why do you need hex strings ? Maybe there are better method to do something with this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the raw image to a hex string, get the `bytes` using `tobytes()` and then convert to hex with the `binascii` module.

```
import binascii

im_bytes = im.tobytes()
im_hex = binascii.hexlify(im_bytes)
```

To convert it to a compressed format (JPG, PNG) in a hex string:

```
import binascii
import io

im_bytes = io.BytesIO()
im.save(im_bytes, format='JPEG')
im_hex = binascii.hexlify(im_bytes.getvalue())
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but you can not save in different name.

Answer (score 0):

Read in a jpg and make a string of hex values. Then reverse the procedure. Take a string of hex and write it out as a jpg file...

```py
import binascii

with open('my_img.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    
im_hex = binascii.hexlify(data)

# check out the hex...
print(im_hex[:10])

# reversing the procedure
im_hex = binascii.a2b_hex(im_hex)
print(im_hex[:10])

# write it back out to a jpg file
with open('my_hex.jpg', 'wb') as image_file:
    image_file.write(im_hex)
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of why this solution may be better than the currently accepted answer. Answers with no explanation, regardless of how trivial, are expected on this site. It helps users understand what is going on in the code.

Comment: I couldn't get the accepted answer to work.